# Raspberry Pi - Error resizing existing FAT partition

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, sd-card

I tried to install RASPBIAN os using noobs in to my pi. But when I start the pi after coping the noobs into my sd card, it shows the folling error.

> Error resizing existing FAT partition

How to fix it, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you follow a guide for installing it?

Comment: I watched some tutorials. not the guide, now i'll check it

Comment: The official guide is a great help, I've installed the OS on several occasions using these guides: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This usually happens when raspberry cannot read the SD data, and you can fix it by doing a lot of things, for example:

- Change the SD card, format the new one of FAT32 and put all of Raspbian data inside it
- Get your current SD card and format it again, try to check if this is ok to read/write
- Go to this [link](https://github.com/recalbox/recalbox-os/wiki/Compatibility-%28EN%29) and check if your SD card compatibility
- Check if your power supply is really 5V, and if its passing to Rasp, sometimes rasp doesn't work well because it hasn't enough power

Comment: I just wanna add if someone is having the same trouble on windows or MAC then use SDFormatter for format , and instead of quick format use overwrite format option, that helped for me

Comment: You can also format the sd card by putting it in an Android cellphone. Go to settings> Storage> format sd card. Then put the sd card in your pc. delete any files that may be formed. Copy the unzipped noobs in the sd card and you are good to go.